# Options for streaming audio from other sources to the Pi's audio jack

Tags: audio, streaming, shairplay

What I want to do:

Be able to stream all audio from other devices (Android, Windows, Linux) to the Audio Jack of the Raspberry pi with minimum latency.

What I tried:

```
- shairport: Has delay issues. Streams audio with a delay of 2 to 3 seconds no matter what delay I set on streaming device. Though, works with good Android clients (AllStream).
- shairport-sync: Doesn't have good Android clients. Tried AllStream but the speaks go mute randomly for some time. Though, works with AirAudio (I don't like AirAudio).
```

What I need:

Suggestions for a audio streaming service which streams audio with negligible delay and has working clients on all platforms. Options not limited to AirPlay. Any good solution will work. Should run on Raspbian.

What I don't need:

A full OS image which contains the required service.

Comment: *"Be able to stream all audio from other devices (Android, Windows, Linux) to the Audio Jack of the Raspberry pi with minimum latency."* ->
This depends on **how** (and whether) those devices stream audio, which is why, e.g., you are running into issues with shairplay.  So you have to solve the problem by installing corresponding software on those devices as well -- there is no magic bullet, and I do not think there is a solution which will work with *any* form of audio streaming, particularly since some of them will be proprietary.

Comment: I'd start by investigating [DNLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Living_Network_Alliance), since there are clients and servers available for the pi and all common operating systems, including mobile.  Also, logically enough, you will have to set up *a* connection between two devices, you cannot stream *all* of them, not so much because it will be a cacophony but because you will rapidly run out of available bandwidth on the pi.

Comment: 1. I'm expecting to stream audio of a single device at a single time.     2. I did install corresponding software of shairport which I have already mentioned. Working was not the issue. The issue was the 2 second audio delay.    3. Please suggest a good dlna audio receiver with minimum lag.

Comment: streaming media will always require a small delay for buffering. i dont know a solution that works real time. even with sonos... shairport-sync works with same senders as shairport/airplay. in both ports you can change the delay / buffer time. another options are Bluetooth or for network dnla, squeezebox, mpd or even pulseaudio over network.

Comment: @JoePlatano While networking of any sort involves buffering on some level just to decode packets, that does not mean it needs to involve a latency significantly noticeable to human beings.  Video conferencing or monitoring obviously is networked, includes audio (or may), and is close enough to human "real time" to be feasible.  Latency in those applications is usually due to the network itself, and should seem fairly instantaneous with ping times < 100 ms (a home LAN should be < 10 ms unless unusually stressed).

Comment: @goldilocks I agree. But even if there are a few frames that are buffered for keep the stream in sync, its a delay even if you normaly dont notice.  this 2-3 secs about99ninjas mentioned seems much... maybe its the time for establish the stream while  switching output on the client?

Comment: If whatever depends on pulseaudio on the Pi side (which it likely may), then the last time I used that as an audio client/server, it definitely introduced noticeable latency in the "multiple seconds" range. *Why* it does that I have no idea, but it would be hard to blame anything other than poor design, or perhaps a design that sacrifices latency to prioritize other goals.

Answer (score -3):

The answer is [UV4L](http://linux-projects.org). You can stream any audio input source from the Android, PC, etc... with browser to the Raspberry Pi. No configuration. No latency.

Comment: There's no such thing as UV4L for Windows.

Comment: *"You can stream any audio input source from the Android"* is also false, since Android does not have a universal audio network output stream; they exist per application.  E.g., good luck streaming Spotify to anything except another device running Spotify.   This is a implicit issue in the question, but I presume the OP either is aware of this or will find out...

Comment: read better I said *with a browser*

Comment: @goobering don't you have a browser on windows?

Comment: This is hardly of much value as an answer then.  The question was not "from a browser" and depending on context redirecting audio through a browser will vary from PITA to impossible.

Comment: I look forward to reading your proposed solution using a browser inside windows to create a latency free audio stream using UV4L. Could you add it to your answer?

Comment: @goobering I'm guessing there may be some way to connect to an HTTP server on the UV4L enabled device (i.e., the pi), although I'm very dubious about how that is supposed to work on *any* platform -- meaning this answer is extremely confused.

Comment: @goldilocks then you certainly do not know what browsers are capable of nowadays. secondly, the question does not say "not from a browser" either. third, it's actually a good thing that you can do this from a browser.

Comment: **I don't believe you** but I would be happy to be proven wrong if you would like to include a more detailed explanation of what you mean in your answer.  For example, I am using a web browser right now.  Let's say I am also playing audio on the same computer that I would like to stream to a Raspberry Pi.  What is it that I should do with the browser on this computer (of any sort) to make this possible?  I think you have misread the question to mean *from* a Pi, not *to* a Pi.

Comment: @goldilocks too bad you don't believe me, but people can test that along the lines of this old demo (showing video to rpi): https://youtu.be/yhxnAmJsT_E?list=PLT2HCg4Nbo1upDmqPFxyT8koQwvCcUOph . I could stream audio too in two clicks: one for selecting my sound card as default input device, another one for selecting the input device for stream to the rpi from within the browser. On the rpi, I disabled the uv4l voice detection and other nice stuff that would be okay for voice but not for music.

Comment: There's a note right there which says "audio cast is not ready yet - except mic".  Also, it absolutely cannot be done on any platform without installing software there first, because there are way too many security restrictions placed on the browser for it to be otherwise.  So this may work for you to do particular things on particular systems, but it certainly comes no where close to satisfying the criteria in the question.

Comment: @goldilocks: it's evident you deliberately keep ignoring or being obtuse. I said old example and I also told how to reproduce it. Anyway, I do not need to convince you. But WebRTC Audio API certainly exists on any browsers without installing any plug-ins or additional software - that's its purpose (and that's the thing  UV4L is doing). Good luck.

Comment: The additional software would be required to feed audio to the WebRTC plugin.  Again, this answer may be useful for certain purposes but does not fit this question.

Comment: @goldilocks: no, again, no plugin exists or is required as browsers implement WebRTC natively. It's also being standardized. The protocol allows you to select a device for streaming, the browser thinks of everything for the streaming to take place. To me, if you can just open your browser to stream your music to the Rpi, then this is THE answer.

Comment: If all this is possible you should be able to provide *one, simple example* paralleling the use, e.g., shairplay, since it is used as such in the question.  I have a library of music on my computer.  How I am going to stream anything from that via the browser to the Pi?  What port do I even connect to? Etc.  If you cannot do that, then you at best have a hint that most likely leads to a dead end.  I do look forward to the day when everything is this simple, but I am not holding my breath.

Comment: @goldilocks actually one can stream all audio from Android to shairport (that's what I'm doing right now). Plus, currently I'm listening to music from Spotify directly on the speakers connected to RasPi. Also, the problem with stream going mute randomly in shairport-sync was fixed by turning of the audio synconisation. Though due to this, apparently ldistortiooccursn . But as a temporary fix, I can stream all audio from Android to RasPi by using shairport-sync on RasPi and AllStream on Android (it needs root probably that's how the developer made it possible to go around the issue umentione)

Comment: Besides agreeing with @goldilocks comments your answer provides no details on how to do this.